# Show that exists a finite subset in $\mathcal{L}$-theory

Tags: model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a language and let $T$ and $T^{\prime}$ be $\mathcal{L}$-theories. Suppose that for every model $\mathcal{M}$ of $T$ there exists $\sigma \in T^{\prime}$ such that $\mathcal{M} \models \sigma$. How to show that there exists a finite subset $\{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\}$ of $T^{\prime}$ such that $T \models \sigma_1 \vee \cdots \vee \sigma_n$ ?

I was thinking to look at $T \cup \{ \neg \sigma \mid \sigma \in T^{\prime}\}$, because we know that $T \models \sigma$, so $T \cup \{ \neg \sigma \}$ is inconsistent, and then to apply Compactness theorem II. Something like that.

Comment: In your statement "**..we know that $T\models\sigma$, so $T\cup\{\lnot\sigma\}$ is inconsistent**" - what is $\sigma$? ..we just know that $\forall M[M\models T\rightarrow \exists \sigma\in T′(M\models\sigma)]$. We do **not** know $T\models\sigma$?

Comment: It seems to me that it works ... Due to the fact that $T \cup \{¬σ ∣ σ \in T′ \}$ is *unsatisfiable*, we apply *Compactness* to conclude that it is not *finitely satisfiable*. Then, exists $n$ such that $T \cup \{¬σ_i ∣ σ_i \in T′, 1 \le i \le n \}$ is *unsat*. From this follows : $T \vDash \lnot(\lnot \sigma_1 \land \ldots \lnot \sigma_n)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @tomasz Is YonedaLenna right? Because choosing $\sigma$ depends on $\mathcal{M}$, so do we really have $T \models \sigma$? I am confused now.

Comment: I think that Yoneda is right : we cannot say : $T⊨σ$. But my comment omits this unnecessary fact. We say correctly that $T \cup \{ ¬σ ∣ σ \in T′ \}$ is *unsat*, because for every model $M$ of $T$ we have at last one $\sigma \in T'$ such that $\sigma$ is true in **that** model $M$ of $T$.

Comment: @Cortizol: Yes, I agree with Mauro and YonedaLemma. If you knew that $T\models \sigma$, you would not need compactness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption $T\cup\{\neg\sigma:\sigma\in T'\}$ is inconsistent. By compcatness  $T\cup\{\neg\sigma_1\dots,\neg\sigma_n\}$ is inconsistent for some $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n\in T'$. Hence $T\models\sigma_1 \vee \cdots \vee \sigma_n$

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize Mauro Allegranza had already answered. If he turns his comment into an answer I will delete mine.